# Merge columns with more than one value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got this DataFrame in Python using pandas:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hello | a,b,c | 1,2,3 |
| hi | b,c,a | 4,5,6 |

The values in column 3 belong to the categories in column 2.
Is there a way to combine columns 2 and 3 that I get this output?

| Column 1 | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| hi | 6 | 4 | 5 |

Any advise will be very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Column 3'].split(','), index=x['Column2'].split(',')), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

result make to `df1` and `concat`

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Column 3'].split(','), index=x['Column2'].split(',')), axis=1)

pd.concat([df['Column 1'], df1], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    col1    a   b   c
0   hello   1   2   3
1   hi      4   5   6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.crosstab` after `exploding` the commas:

```
new_df = ( df.assign(t=df['Column 2'].str.split(','), a=df['Column 3'].str.split(',')).
                      explode(['t', 'a']) )

output = ( pd.crosstab(index=new_df['Column 1'], columns=new_df['t'], 
                     values=new_df['a'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index() )
```

Output:

```
t   Column 1    a   b   c
0   hello       1   2   3
1   hi          4   5   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency wise, I'd say do all the wrangling in vanilla python and create a new dataframe:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
outcome = defaultdict(list)
for column, row in zip(df['Column 2'], df['Column 3']):
    column = column.split(',')
    row = row.split(',')
    for first, last in zip(column, row):
        outcome[first].append(last)
pd.DataFrame(outcome).assign(Column = df['Column 1'])
   a  b  c Column
0  1  2  3  hello
1  6  4  5     hi
```